# React/Redux - child component with Redux updates on some parent state changes, not on others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my React app, I'm experiencing a problem where a component that pulls from the Redux state does not update during some, but not all, state changes of its parent component - this is causing me some trouble, and I'd like to understand why some parent component state changes are registering and others are not.

I've provided relevant excerpts from the parent (`User.jsx`) and child (`MembershipList.jsx`) components below, but in brief summary, the problem is as follows:

In `User.jsx`, the function `addGroup` adds objects to the 'leader' or 'member' array attributes of the 'groups' state object - when the state updates, `MembershipList.jsx` is updated with data from those objects.  This function works just fine, as noted in the code below.

The function `removeGroup` is supposed to be the opposite of `addGroup` - it updates the state by removing objects from the group arrays.  Currently, this function successfully updates the state of `User.jsx`, but the `MembershipList.jsx` child component does not update to match. I am lead to believe that this has something to do with the use of the Redux state in `Membership.jsx`, because if I simply replace `export default connect(mapStateToProps, undefined)(MembershipList)` with `export default MembershupList`, this functionality works as desired - the parent state updates and the child re-renders correctly.

`User.jsx` (excerpt)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class User extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.removeGroup = this.removeGroup.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            groups: {
                leader: [],
                member: []
            }
        }
    }

    // THIS FUNCTION SUCCESSFULLY UPDATES THE STATE AND THE MembershipList.jsx COMPONENT
    addGroup(groupData, grouprole) {
        let groupToAdd = JSON.parse(groupData)
        let groupsToUpdate = this.state.groups;
        groupsToUpdate[grouprole] = [...groupsToUpdate[grouprole], groupToAdd]
        this.setState({groups: groupsToUpdate})
    }

    // THIS FUNCTION SUCCESSFULLY UPDATES THE STATE,
    // BUT THE MembershipList.jsx COMPONENT FAILS TO UPDATE
    removeGroup(groupId, grouprole) {
        let groupsToUpdate = this.state.groups;
        for (let i = 0; i < groupsToUpdate[grouprole].length; i ++){
            if (groupId === groupsToUpdate[grouprole][i].id){
                groupsToUpdate[grouprole].splice(i, 1)
                this.setState({groups: groupsToUpdate})
            }
        }
    }

    render(){
        // ABBREVIATING - THIS IS THE RELEVANT COMPONENT
        <MembershipList
            groups={this.state.groups.leader}
            legend={"Leader"}
            removeGroup={this.removeGroup}
            parent="edit_user"
            grouprole={"leader"}
            openModal={this.openModal}
            hideModal={this.hideModal} />
    }

}

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(User);
```

`MembershipList.jsx` (excerpt - this is the component that fails to update on certain state changes of `User.jsx`)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    state
});

class MembershipList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.removeGroup = this.removeGroup.bind(this);
        this.modalReference = "group";
    }

    removeGroup(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.removeGroup(event.target.dataset.groupid, this.props.grouprole);
    }

    render() {
        let membershipList;

        if(this.props.parent === "edit_user" || this.props.parent === "new_user"){
            membershipList =    <ul className="membership_list">
                                    {
                                        this.props.groups.map((group, i) => (
                                            <li className="membership_list_item" key={i}>
                                                <a onClick={() => this.props.openModal(group.id, this.modalReference)}>{group.name}</a>
                                                <button className="remove_button btn btn-warning" onClick={this.removeGroup} data-groupid={group.id}>Remove</button>
                                            </li>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </ul>
        }
        else{
            // HERE, membershipList IS A SIMILAR BIT OF HTML AS ABOVE, THOUGH IT REFERENCES THE REDUX STATE
            // HOWEVER, THIS CONDITION IS NOT EXECUTED DURING THE TROUBLESOME CHAIN OF EVENTS
        }

        return(
            <fieldset className="MembershipList">
                <legend>{this.props.legend}</legend>
                <div className="membership_list_container">
                    {membershipList}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, undefined)(MembershipList)
```

Apart from the fact that I would like to get this fixed, I would like to know why this is occurring - why is it that parent state changes that increase the length of the arrays in the state's 'groups' attribute re-render the child, while parent state changes that decrease the length of those arrays fails to update the child?  I've dropped some `console.log`s in the child's `render` function and they are logged when increasing (`addGroup`) but nothing is logged when they are decreasing (`removeGroup`).  Can anyone offer some thoughts?

Comment: Hard to tell if this the only cause, but in your remove, your using splice, which only mutates the array, rather than replacing it like in your add.

Comment: [Take a look at the connect docs and how it compares incoming new props](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Comment: Typo: `this.setState({groups: goupsToUpdate})`. Goups? Note: linting would have caught that error. You should probably look into using it in your dev workflow.

Comment: @Andy thanks for the catch, but that's just a typo that I made transferring some of the code - I changed a few variable names to be a bit more illustrative and just mistyped that.

Comment: @enjoylife thanks - the function `areOwnPropsEqual` might be helpful. Will let you know.

Comment: @enjoylife - Your suggestion about not using `splice()` was what solved it - I replaced `groupsToUpdate[grouprole].splice(i, 1)` with `groupsToUpdate[grouprole] = groupsToUpdate[grouprole].filter(a => a !== i)` and that did the trick. For whatever reason, the child component would re-render with `splice()` when it (the child) wasn't wired with Redux, but that wasn't sufficient once Redux was in the the mix. If you'd parse your suggestion as an answer to my question, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: @enjoylife Actually, this is odd - it only works if both the `splice` and `filter` lines are used (I left `splice` in by mistake, but it was what worked). It only works if I mutate the array and then replace it - can't just replace it.  I have a feeling that I'm just not setting the state correctly - I think I need to use React immutability helpers, since it's a nested part of the state...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big thanks to @enjoylife for pointing me in the right direction on this... he/she really deserves the credit, but I'm answering my own question because my perspective on this problem will allow me to provide a more well-formed answer and will maybe be of help to someone else in this situation.

In a nutshell, the original structure of my app was using Redux in the parent component (`User.jsx`) but not in the child component (`MembershipList.jsx`), and the way that I had written the `removeGroup()` function was, while probably less than perfect, working just fine.

However, for reasons that I personally don't understand, that function started to fail to update the child component once I added Redux to that component, too - `splice()` returns a mutated version of the original array, rather than a new array, and the child component was no longer responding to changes in the state originating with the `splice()` method.

@enjoylife hit the nail on the head by pointing this out - I needed a more robust method of updating the state. I used the React `immutability-helper` module (https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) to accomplish this. Here are the relevant changes to `User.jsx` -

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import update from 'immutability-helper';


removeGroup(groupId, grouprole) {
    let groupsToUpdate = this.state.groups;
    for (let i = 0; i < groupsToUpdate[grouprole].length; i ++){
        if (groupId === groupsToUpdate[grouprole][i].id){
            let updatedRoleArray = update(groupsToUpdate[grouprole], {$splice: [[i, 1]]});
            groupsToUpdate[grouprole] = updatedRoleArray;
            this.setState({groups: groupsToUpdate})
        }
    }
}
```